# Are Euclidean spaces $\Delta$-generated?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, simplicial-stuff, locally-presentable-categories

From the definition of $\Delta$-generated it seems like $\mathbb R$ should be $\Delta$-generated, as $\mathbb R$ is final with respect to all continuous maps $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

However, the paper [2] says that a Tychonoff space $X$ is $\Delta$ generated if and only if $C_p(X)$ is distinguished, and from the work [1] (§5, Corollary 5.4, p. 96, statement (1)), "The existence of an uncountable separable metrizable space such that $C_p(X)$ is distinguished, is independent of ZFC."

Does this mean that the Euclidean spaces are not in fact $\Delta$-generated, as they are uncountable separable metrizable spaces?

**References**

[1] Jerzy Ka̧kol and Arkady Leiderman, "[A characterization of $X$ for which spaces $C_p(X)$ are distinguished and its applications](https://www.ams.org/journals/bproc/2021-08-08/S2330-1511-2021-00076-7/)", Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Series B, 8, pp. 86-99 (2021), [MR4214339](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=4214339), [Zbl 1473.54018](https://zbmath.org/1473.54018).

[2] Arkady Leiderman and Paul Szeptycki, "On $\Delta$-spaces", [arXiv:2307.16047v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.16047) [math.GN].

Comment: Hi, welcome to MathOverflow! Quick clarification: isn't that 2023 paper on arxiv about $\Delta$-spaces instead of $\Delta$-generated spaces?

Comment: Could you give the definition of $\Delta$-generated spaces for those that have never heard of it?  Also, what is the purpose of this concept?

Comment: @DavidWhite I think that probably solves it.

Comment: @RyanBudney I was looking at $\Delta$-generated spaces using this definition: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Delta-generated+topological+space, and while looking for papers on it I think I got my $\Delta$'s confused

Comment: Okay, that article answers your questions.  CW-complexes are $\Delta$-generated, and Euclidean space admits a CW-structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yesterday, I answered in a comment, but I'll give a more detailed answer today so that this question doesn't linger on the unanswered queue. First, the idea of $\Delta$-generated spaces is just like "compactly generated" spaces but we generate by topological simplices rather than compact Hausdorff spaces. That means the topology on a $\Delta$-generated space $X$ is determined by continuous functions $\Delta^n_\text{top} \to X$.

The upshot is that the category of $\Delta$-generated spaces is locally presentable, which is very useful in homotopy theory. The category of $\Delta$-generated spaces is big enough to include most spaces we care about as algebraic topologists, including all CW complexes, all smooth manifolds, and all topological manifolds, but small enough to have good category-theoretic properties (like, being generated under filtered colimits by a set of objects). It does not contain all metrizable spaces. An example worth knowing is that the topologist's sine curve is not a $\Delta$-generated space despite being a closed subspace of one (namely, $\mathbb{R}^2$).

The OP might be interested to know that, if you start with the interval $I$, and create $I$-generated spaces, what you get is exactly the same as the class of $\Delta$-generated spaces. The same is true is you start from $\mathbb{R}$. Hence, some authors write "numerically-generated" or "Euclidean-generated" instead of $\Delta$-generated. So, not only can you "generate" $\mathbb{R}^n$ from the topological simplices, but you can go the other way, too. You can read about this observation and more on the [nLab page for Delta-generated spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Delta-generated+topological+space).

Now, a $\Delta$-space is something entirely different (defined in Def 1.2 of the arxiv paper the OP links to), and $\Delta$-complexes (e.g., from Hatcher's book) are different again. This MO thread will hopefully save future researchers from getting confused between these notions.

Comment: All locally path-connected, first countable spaces are numerically generated, and this includes all topological manifolds.

Comment: @Tyrone Great! I updated the answer. I had been thinking in terms of triangulations.

Comment: FWIW, every topological space has a $\Delta$-generification, and if I'm not mistaken the universal map from it to the original space is a weak homotopy equivalence, and induces an isomorphism on singular cohomology. Thus for most purposes of algebraic topology, since CW-complexes are $\Delta$-generated, you have everything you need, including nice categorical properties.